# What exactly is the optimization `functools.partial` is making?

Tags: python, performance, cpython, python-internals, functools

CPython 3.6.4:

```
from functools import partial

def add(x, y, z, a):
    return x + y + z + a

list_of_as = list(range(10000))

def max1():
    return max(list_of_as , key=lambda a: add(10, 20, 30, a))

def max2():
    return max(list_of_as , key=partial(add, 10, 20, 30))
```

now:

```
In [2]: %timeit max1()
4.36 ms ± 42.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit max2()
3.67 ms ± 25.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I thought `partial` just remembers part of parameters and then forwards them to the original function when called with the rest of the parameters (so it's nothing more than a shortcut), but it seems it makes some optimization. In my case the whole `max2` function gets optimized by 15% compared to the `max1`, which is pretty nice.

It would be great to know what the optimization is, so I could use it in a more efficient way. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial) are silent regarding any optimization. Not surprisingly, "roughly equivalent to" implementation (given in docs), does not optimize at all:

```
In [3]: %timeit max2()  # using `partial` implementation from docs 
10.7 ms ± 267 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: did not know about partial, thanks for bringing it to my attention. As a hazarded guess: your overhead of creating new stack frames is less with partial involved as it only needs to store one variable instead of all four -but thats just a hazy (and most probably wrong) guess. I am waiting for the pros to pipe in for an in depth explanation :)

Comment: Any difference if instead of a lambda, you use a ‘def’?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I just checked (created an external `def helper(a): return add(10, 20, 30, a)` and used it in `max`) and there is no difference in speed.

Comment: Did you try partial implementation from python sources?  (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L234)

Comment: @soon I just did (by simply copying `class partial` into my code) and it's ever worse than "roughly equivalent to" one:

`17.7 ms ± 595 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: There are also C sources for `partial`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3070b71e5eedf62e49b8e7dedab75742a5f67ece/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c

Comment: And seems like `try / catch` just after python's implementation shall overwrite python's class with C based implementation

Comment: @soon Right. With this line added I'm back with `3.67 ms +/-`. Unfortunately I'm no so good with C to quickly (enough) understand the optimization that is going on there.

Comment: I think the optimization is simply that it is written in C, not something special it does in the C implementation. Python-level function calls are pretty expensive, doing them from C is faster.

Comment: Well, I am also not an expert in C, but I think the answer you are looking for should be in the [`partial_fastcall`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3070b71e5eedf62e49b8e7dedab75742a5f67ece/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L130) function implementation. Looks like it is optimized for functions with a small number of arguments. Though I may be wrong

Comment: One difference is that `max1` needs to lookup `add` in the global scope for each call while `max2` only does the lookup once. Adding `add=add` as a lambda parameter will make it faster. Alternatively, you can put it in a local variable of `max1`.

Comment: @interjay Adding `add=add` to `max1`s parameters did improve the speed but not as much: `4.5 ms ± 28.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 100 loops each)` (old max1) vs `4.41 ms ± 70.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 20 runs, 100 loops each)` (new max1). I increased timeit's repetitions from 7 to 20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following arguments actually apply only to CPython, for other Python implementations it could be completely different. You actually said your question is about CPython but nevertheless I think it's important to realize that these in-depth questions almost always depend on implementation details that might be different for different implementations and might even be different between different CPython versions (for example CPython 2.7 could be completely different, but so could be CPython 3.5)!

### Timings

First of all, I can't reproduce differences of 15% or even 20%. On my computer the difference is around ~10%. It's even less when you change the `lambda` so it doesn't have to look up `add` from the global scope (as already pointed out in the comments you can pass the `add` function as default argument to the function so the lookup happens in the local scope).

```
from functools import partial

def add(x, y, z, a):
    return x + y + z + a

def max_lambda_default(lst):
    return max(lst , key=lambda a, add=add: add(10, 20, 30, a))

def max_lambda(lst):
    return max(lst , key=lambda a: add(10, 20, 30, a))

def max_partial(lst):
    return max(lst , key=partial(add, 10, 20, 30))
```

I actually benchmarked these:

[image]

```
from simple_benchmark import benchmark
from collections import OrderedDict

arguments = OrderedDict((2**i, list(range(2**i))) for i in range(1, 20))
b = benchmark([max_lambda_default, max_lambda, max_partial], arguments, "list size")

%matplotlib notebook
b.plot_difference_percentage(relative_to=max_partial)
```

### Possible explanations

It's very hard to find the exact reason for the difference. However there are a few possible options, assuming you have a [CPython version with compiled `_functools` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/functools.py#L319-L322) (all desktop versions of CPython that I use have it).

As you already found out the [Python version of `partial`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/functools.py#L236-L317) will be significantly slower.

- `partial` is implemented in C and can call the function directly - without intermediate Python layer<sup>1</sup>. The `lambda` on the other hand needs to do a Python level call to the "captured" function.
- `partial` actually knows how the arguments fit together. So it can create the arguments that are passed to the function more efficiently (it just [concatenats the stored argument tuple to the passed in argument tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L77)) instead of building a completely new argument tuple.
- In more recent Python versions several internals were changed in an effort to optimize function calls (the so called FASTCALL optimization). Victor Stinner has a list of related pull requests on his [blog](https://vstinner.github.io/fastcall-issues.html) in case you want to find out more about it.

  That probably will affect both the `lambda` and the `partial` but again because `partial` is a C function it *knows* which one to call directly without having to *infer* it like `lambda` does.

However it's very important to realize that creating the `partial` has some overhead. The break-even point is for ~10 list elements, if the list is shorter, then the `lambda` will be faster.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> If you call a function from Python it uses the OP-code `CALL_FUNCTION` which is actually a [wrapper (that's what I meant with Python layer) around the `PyObject_Call*` (or FASTCAL) functions](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/ceval.c#L4805-L4867). But it also includes creating the argument tuple/dictionary. If you call a function from a C function you can avoid this thin wrapper by directly calling the `PyObject_Call*` functions.

In case you're interested about the OP-Codes, you can [`dis`assemble the function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
import dis
    
dis.dis(max_lambda_default)

 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (max)
 2 LOAD_FAST                0 (lst)
 4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (add)
 6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
 8 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda>>)
10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('max_lambda_default.<locals>.<lambda>')
12 MAKE_FUNCTION            1 (defaults)
14 LOAD_CONST               3 (('key',))
16 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         2
18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda>>:
 0 LOAD_FAST                1 (add)      <--- (2)
 2 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
 4 LOAD_CONST               2 (20)
 6 LOAD_CONST               3 (30)
 8 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
10 CALL_FUNCTION            4            <--- (1)
12 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the `CALL_FUNCTION` op code (1) is actually in there.

As an aside: The `LOAD_FAST` (2) is responsible for the performance difference between the `lambda_default` and the `lambda` without default (which has to resort to a slower lookup). That's because loading a name actually starts by checking the local scope (the function scope), in the case of `add=add` the add function is in the local scope, so it can make a faster lookup. If you don't have it in the local scope it will check each surrounding scope until it finds the name and it only stops when it reaches the global scope. And that lookup is done every time the `lambda` is called!

Comment: Isn't `functools.partial` implemented in Python since Python 3.4? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L234

Comment: @PeterNimroot That's just a fallback in case you don't have the compiled `_functools` module ([the class is overwritten by an import shortly after](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L312-L315)). And it's very rare that you don't have that.

Comment: @MSeifert small precision wrt name resolution: `LOAD_NAME` is because `compile` has no idea what the scopes are here, if you `dis.dis(lambda a: add(10, 20, 30, a)`) you'll find that the function body uses the specialised `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `LOAD_FAST` rather than the more general `LOAD_NAME`. `LOAD_FAST` can directly index into the frame's local namespace instead of having to go through looking up and resolving the name making it especially fast. With `lambda a, add=add: add(10, 20, 30, a)` the `add` is also `LOAD_FAST`-ed, which is why this form is noticeably faster (& a common optimisation).

Comment: @Masklinn That's kind of what I meant. The `LOAD_NAME` makes it slower - what happenes if you don't use it as default. However the answer is 3 years old now ... so probably a few things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: @MSeifert the `LOAD_NAME` would not be present in the lambda though, one would `LOAD_GLOBAL` the `add` while the other would `LOAD_LOCAL` it. The presence of `LOAD_NAME` is an artefact of dis-ing a string. I don't think this has changed in a while.

Comment: @Masklinn Ah I understand what you're saying now and have updated the answer.